# checkbox is always unchecked

Tags: android, checkbox

in the below code i am trying to use a checkbox. but at run time it is never clickable, i mean when i click on the check box nothing happen or change and the checkbox remains always unchecked

why that is happening?

**code**:

```
mcbComputations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mcbComputations.isChecked()) {
            mATComputations = new ATComputations();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                mATComputations.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            } else {
                mATComputations.execute();
            }
        } else {
            mATComputations.cancel(true);
        }
```

Comment: `mcbComputations` stands for `CheckBox`?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes it does

Comment: `onCheckChanged` should be used to capture checked state.

Comment: I think when override click listener for a checkbox, you should call its super implementation to check/uncheck your check box, your check/uncheck your check box manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with a Checkbox, rather use an `onCheckChangedListener`:

```
        mcbComputations.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (mcbComputations.isChecked()) {

                    mATComputations = new ATComputations();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        mATComputations.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    } else {
                        mATComputations.execute();
                    }

                } else {
                    mATComputations.cancel(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
setOnCheckedChangeListener
```

instead of

```
setOnClickListener
```

for `CheckBox`